# VSCode is self defining environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I have this env variable `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` that is set in one of my project `.env` and loaded via direnv. Anyway, it should be project specific, and not handled by VSCode.

The problem is that when opening another project, `echo $BUNDLE_GEMFILE` in code's integrated terminal shows the value of the variable, that **should not be set**. Opening an external terminal, `echo $BUNDLE_GEMFILE` shows nothing, which is the expected behaviour.

A hotfix would be to set `"terminal.integrated.env.osx": { "BUNDLE_GEMFILE": null }`. But I need to know the source of the issue to be sure that there is no other env pollution

---

<sub>**NOTE:** I know that I've had this problem in the past, yet I don't remember the solution I've found, and I'm struggling here, if I find, I'll share the answer. On internet all the posts are about how to set, now how to avoid. Please feel free to update the question terms to make it relevent for ppl searching for that.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the `inheritEnv` setting. Setting it to false avoid that:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
```

This still doesn't say why this is in vs code env unfortunately.